# How to add post query parameter string with double quote in url in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am accessing an api .which looks like

`http://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX/api/Gallery/getgallerylist?userid="17"` .

I have tried the following annotation.

```
 @POST("Gallery/getgallerylist")
    Call<GalleryImagesResponse> getGalleryImages(@Query("userid") String userid);
```

But the url it requests is `http://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX/api/Gallery/getgallerylist?userid=17`

So that how can I add double quote to userid's value like userid="17".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the string as `@Path` to the URL like this.

```
@POST("http://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX/api/Gallery/getgallerylist?" + "{path}")
Call<ResponseBody> getGalleryImages(@Path("path") String path);
```

and pass `userid=17` to this call, it will append to the URL. and your done

Comment: @Joison,I tried as your suggestion,But I got following error.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "{userid}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
   for method ApiInterface.getGalleryImages

Comment: replace `@Post` to `@Get` annotation. check you code and correct it. You cannot use `@Query` with `@Post`

Comment: Sorry.I changed now.no luck.

Comment: The same error which I mentioned in previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

> you should try this before hitting `url`

```
URLDecoder.decode(url,UTF8);
```